# Why does ssh -g say that address is already in use?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I setup an SSH connection with port forwarding that allows remote hosts to connect to the local forwarded ports like this:

```
ssh -g -L 5115:localhost:5115 <server>
```

The connection works fine even though I get this error message:

> bind: Address already in use

I get this message no matter what ports I choose.  I'm wondering why I get this message even though the connection appears to work flawlessly.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is (on both systems) the output of `netstat --inet --inet6 -nlp | grep 5115`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging There is no output on either box before I run the SSH command

Comment: Unless I'm missing something... `-g` allows remote hosts to connect to a forwarded port.  'localhost' tells it to bind to an IP that cannot be reached by a remote host.  Change localhost to the local system's IP address (not 127.0.0.1) and see what you get.

Comment: That is strange. For a better understanding of the problem you can run `ssh` through `strace` and have a look at the last syscalls before the error message: `strace -o ssh.strace ssh -g -L 5115:localhost:5115 <server>`. Terminate `ssh` as soon as the connection is established and have a look at the file `ssh.strace`.

Comment: @yoonix I tried using the IP address instead of localhost but I still got the same message :-/

Comment: @Kurtis - what does adding a `-vvv` show in terms of debug messages? Also do you already have another SSH connection using this port (-L 5115) to a different `<server>`? Also take a look at this tip: https://www.learnosity.com/blog/2008/02/ssh-portforward-address-already-in-use-solved/

Comment: @Kurtis - take a look at this cheatsheet as well: http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html

Comment: I am using openssh 6.6p1-2 and I don't see the the bind message when performing the port forward. What version of openssh are you using? What OS?

Comment: @yoonix no, the host in the middle of `-L cport:shost:sport` is the host the *server* talks to, for tunnelled connections. The *client* end listens on loopback (127.1) by default, which allows only processes on localhost to connect; `-g` causes it to listen instead on ANYADDR (0 or ::0) which allows remote process as well. Alternatively you can specify *four* parts: `-L cbind:cport:shost:sport`. If `-L cport:cIP:sport` did work, it would encrypt the traffic from client to server and then send it right back to client in clear, destroying the intended security.

Answer (score 2):

The command:

```
ssh -g -L 5115:localhost:5115 <server>
```

would cause the local `ssh` process to bind to 0.0.0.0 port 5115 in order to listen for connections to be forwarded. The error message that you're getting indicates that some other process is already bound to this address and port, so `ssh` is unable to do it.

You ought to be able to verify this by running netstat:

```
netstat -an | grep 5115
```

You might see a line like this:

```
tcp4       0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN
```

"LISTEN" means that something is listening for connections. "*.22" is the address and port; 0.0.0.0 or "*" means "any interface".

Your options here are to find the other program which is using port 5115 and make it stop, or else use a different local port for your ssh tunnel.

Comment: `I get this message no matter what ports I choose. `

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Linux, you can make the warning go away by running this (as root):

> echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only

What's going on is that ssh is binding a PF_INET6 socket to `[::]:5115` before it binds a PF_INET socket to `0.0.0.0:5115`. The PF_INET6 socket is bound to both protocols, so the attempt to bind the second socket fails. By turning on `bindv6only` you will keep the PF_INET6 socket's hands off the IPv4 address.

A less disruptive way of getting there is to use the four-arg form of `-L`, where you specify the bind-address explicitly (use `0.0.0.0`).